# GWT custom composite widget that behaves as a single editor

Tags: gwt, widget, editor

I have a composite widget composed by 3 TextBoxes that acts as a "date mask" field, like: **[dd]/[mm]/[yyy]**  (dont ask why I am doing this :), I dont like DateBox and I have to force the user to keep a type of format, so I wrote my own widget). 
Here is the java code:

```java
import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.KeyUpEvent;
import com.google.gwt.uibinder.client.UiBinder;
import com.google.gwt.uibinder.client.UiField;
import com.google.gwt.uibinder.client.UiHandler;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Composite;`enter code here`
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.TextBox;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget;

public class DateMaskWidget extends Composite {

private static DateMaskWidgetUiBinder uiBinder = GWT
        .create(DateMaskWidgetUiBinder.class);

interface DateMaskWidgetUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, DateMaskWidget> {
}

@UiField
TextBox daysTextbox;
@UiField
TextBox monthsTextbox;
@UiField
TextBox yearsTextbox;

public DateMaskWidget() {
    initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));

    daysTextbox.setMaxLength(2);
    monthsTextbox.setMaxLength(2);
    yearsTextbox.setMaxLength(4);
}

@UiHandler("daysTextbox")
 void onKeyUp(KeyUpEvent event)
{
    //if 2 chars were entered focus the next box
    if(daysTextbox.getText().length()==daysTextbox.getMaxLength())
        monthsTextbox.setFocus(true);
}
@UiHandler("monthsTextbox")
 void onKeyUp2(KeyUpEvent event)
{
    //if 2 chars were entered focus the next box
    if(monthsTextbox.getText().length()==monthsTextbox.getMaxLength())
        yearsTextbox.setFocus(true);
}


}
```

Now I'd like  this widget to behave as a single Editor (like a single TextBox), so i can set a value to it by passing a string like xx/xx/xxxx .

**The Question is: which interface do I need to implement and which methods do I need to override to achive this??
Which methods are used in the editor framework to set/get the value of an editor??**

I will need to take the given string (probably passed in a method like setValue() ), split it in 3 parts, and assign each part to the right text box. And same thing for a getValue() method.

Thanks for your help

[Update]

Ok, I implemented both HasValue and IsEditor interfaces as follows:

```
public class DateMaskWidget extends Composite implements HasValue<String>, 

IsEditor<ValueBoxEditor<String>> {

private static DateMaskWidgetUiBinder uiBinder = GWT
        .create(DateMaskWidgetUiBinder.class);

interface DateMaskWidgetUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, DateMaskWidget> {
}



public DateMaskWidget() {
    initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));


}


//...............other code ...................


@Override
public HandlerRegistration addValueChangeHandler(
        ValueChangeHandler<String> handler) {

    //TODO add code here
}

@Override
public ValueBoxEditor<String> asEditor() {
            //TODO add code here

    return null;
}

@Override
public String getValue() {
    String value="";


value+=this.daysTextbox.getValue()+"/"+   
this.monthsTextbox.getValue()+"/"+this.yearsTextbox.getValue();

  return value;
}

@Override
public void setValue(String value) {
    String[] values = value.split("/");
    this.daysTextbox.setValue(values[0]);
    this.monthsTextbox.setValue(values[1]);
    this.yearsTextbox.setValue(values[2]);
    System.out.println("Set Value:"+value);
}

@Override
public void setValue(String value, boolean fireEvents) {
    //TODO add code here
}
```

}

**Now the question is what should I add to asEditor() and addValueChangeHandler()  here?**

asEditor() needs to return an ValueBoxEditor but not sure how to implement this.

thanks again

Comment: You can set MaxLength in UIBinder: maxLength="2"

Answer (score 1):

Implement `HasValue<String>` in your widget.You can addValueChangeHandler too.

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement the same interface as original TextBox:

```
IsEditor<ValueBoxEditor<java.lang.String>>
```

Editor framework will use `ValueBoxEditor.getValue()` and `ValueBoxEditor.setValue(...)` methods.

Comment: Thanks Maksym, just edited the question with the new code. I implemented the IsEditor<ValueBoxEditor<java.lang.String>> and HasValue<String> interfaces, so I think Im close now, but it's not very clear to me how to override the asEditor() method!? Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after looking around into the GWT source code of TextBox and some other classes it extends/implements, here is what I came up with:

```
public class DateMaskWidget extends Composite implements HasValue<String>,   
IsEditor<TakesValueEditor<String>> {

private static DateMaskWidgetUiBinder uiBinder = GWT
        .create(DateMaskWidgetUiBinder.class);

interface DateMaskWidgetUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, DateMaskWidget> {
}

@UiField
TextBox daysTextbox;
@UiField
TextBox monthsTextbox;
@UiField
TextBox yearsTextbox;

private TakesValueEditor<String> editor;
private boolean valueChangeHandlerInitialized;

public DateMaskWidget() {
    initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));

    daysTextbox.setMaxLength(2);
    monthsTextbox.setMaxLength(2);
    yearsTextbox.setMaxLength(4);
}

@UiHandler("daysTextbox")
 void onKeyUp(KeyUpEvent event)
{
    //if 2 chars were entered focus the next box
    if(daysTextbox.getText().length()==daysTextbox.getMaxLength())
        monthsTextbox.setFocus(true);
}
@UiHandler("monthsTextbox")
 void onKeyUp2(KeyUpEvent event)
{
    //if 2 chars were entered focus the next box
    if(monthsTextbox.getText().length()==monthsTextbox.getMaxLength())
        yearsTextbox.setFocus(true);
}


public HandlerRegistration addChangeHandler(ChangeHandler handler) {
    return addDomHandler(handler, ChangeEvent.getType());
  }

@Override
  public HandlerRegistration addValueChangeHandler(ValueChangeHandler<String>  
 handler) {
        // Initialization code
        if (!valueChangeHandlerInitialized) {
          valueChangeHandlerInitialized = true;
          addChangeHandler(new ChangeHandler() {
            public void onChange(ChangeEvent event) {
              ValueChangeEvent.fire(DateMaskWidget.this, getValue());
            }
          });
        }
        return addHandler(handler, ValueChangeEvent.getType());
      }



@Override
public String getValue() {
    String value="";
    value+=this.daysTextbox.getValue()+"/"+
                this.monthsTextbox.getValue()+"/"+this.yearsTextbox.getValue();
    return value;
}

@Override
public void setValue(String value) {
    String[] values = value.split("/");
    if(values.length==3)
    {
        this.daysTextbox.setValue(values[0]);
        this.monthsTextbox.setValue(values[1]);
        this.yearsTextbox.setValue(values[2]);
    }
    else
    {
        this.daysTextbox.setValue("");
        this.monthsTextbox.setValue("");
        this.yearsTextbox.setValue("");
    }
    System.out.println("Set Value:"+value);
}

@Override
public void setValue(String value, boolean fireEvents) {
    setValue(value);
    if(fireEvents)
        ValueChangeEvent.fire(this, value);
}

@Override
public TakesValueEditor<String> asEditor() {
    if (editor == null) {
          editor = ValueBoxEditor.of(this);


        }
        return editor;
}





}
```